# H14 Error regarding favicon when deploying Django app to Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, web-deployment, heroku-cli

Attempting to deploy my Django web application to Heroku.
This is the first time I have ever deployed the app on Heroku however the app works as expected when running at localhost:8000.

I have followed the documentation and can confirm the presense of 'Procfile' in the root directory of the app.

The contents of Procfile are as follows:

`web: gunicorn my_app.wsgi`

This is consistent with the name of the app as referened everywhere in the project directory/folders.
The 'requirements.txt' file is also present, with the necessary dependencies stated within it.

When I deploy the app I get a success message as illustrated below.
[image]

Yet, when I navigate in the browser to the url I see this...
[image]

If I then consult the logs using the commmand `heroku logs --tail --app myapp`
I see the following

```
at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=myapp.herokuapp.com request_id=[REDACTED] fwd="51.9.111.101" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-03-19T19:07:35.123190+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=myapp.herokuapp.com request_id=[REDACTED] fwd="51.9.111.101" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Further investigaton leads me to believe that that there are currently no dynos assigned to the app, so I then attempt to spin up some resources using the following command
`heroku ps:scale web=1`, yet this gives me a console error of
`Scaling dynos... ! ▸    Couldn't find that process type (web).`

At a loss as to what I can do to resolve the issue so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED!

Had moved Procfile to root but had not pushed this change to Git repo and so Heroku could not establish the presence of the file, hence error.